# how to get regex 'or groups' like (foo|bar) working with find -regex? (OS X)

Tags: regex, macos, find, regex-group

Suppose I want to find all .jpg and .png images, using a regex, I'm trying this:

```
find . -regex ".*\.(jpg|png)"
```

But it doesn't work (no results, even though there are jpg and png files present).

Now, if instead of the `(jpg|png)` part I just use `jpg` or `png`, it works fine. Also, if I use `\(jpg\)` it does find the .jpg files, so apparently I have to escape the parentheses (not sure why). But I can't get the "jpg OR png" thing to work, escaping the `|` symbol (thus using `\(jpg\|png\)` in my regex) doesn't work either.

FYI: I'm using `find` on OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Try it in single quotes.

Comment: @Sobrique That would only matter if he had `$` in the regexp.

Comment: Note that `|` is not available in BRE, and it is only supported in ERE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-E` option on OSX `find` for enabling extended regex:

```
find -E . -regex ".*\.(jpg|png)"
```

As per `man find`:

```
-E 
   Interpret regular expressions followed by -regex and -iregex primaries as extended 
   (modern) regular expressions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's).
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I still need to get the hang of all these different regex standards (only recently switched to OS X). This works like a charm now!